# Как виджет сделать прозрачным в tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, виджет

Как widget сделать прозрачным в tkinter? Например, `Label` или `Entry`

Comment: Точнее не прозрачным а 0% видимости виджета

Comment: Я где-то видел такую возможность, что виджет можно прятать, а потом заного его показывать

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы виджет исчезал на какое то время?

Comment: Примерно да, исчезал когда я скажу, и появлялся тоже

Comment: А как сделать это через `.place()`?

Comment: точно так же как и с `pack()` P.s. обновил пример в том вопросе

Comment: Спасибо, попробую завтра посмотреть как это работает